# Convert String to double with precision 2 in swift 3?

Tags: string, swift3, double

Hi I'm trying to convert a string which have 4 precision eg.12.0000 to 12.00.
For this after searching google I'm using code

```
extension Double {
    func roundTo(places:Int) -> Double {
        let divisor = pow(10.0, Double(places))
        return (self * divisor).rounded() / divisor
    }
}
```

to convert `Double("123.0000").roundTo(places: 2)` but I'm getting result as 123.0. Is there is any possible way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Note:I tried and failed in string format and in nsstring methods

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this out

```
extension Double {
    func roundTo(places:Int) -> String {
        return String(format: "%.\(places)f", self)
    }
}

if let roundedOffNumber = Double("12.0000")?.roundTo(places: 2) {
    print(roundedOffNumber)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
extension Double {
    func roundTo(places:Int) -> Double {
        let string = String(format: "%\(Double(places)/10.0)f", self)
        return Double(string) ?? self // If the string was not correct and the conversion to double failed, simply return the non formatted version
    }
}

var test:Double = 123.34556

test.roundTo(places:3) // Double is now 123.345
```

Note that if the Double actually has only zeros as decimals, it will not show them. You'll need to use a formatter to display them when you convert it back to a string